# What match is occured in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Let's imagine i have some regex pattern:

```
(a)|(b)|(c)
```

How to identify what match has been triggered? Is there some kind of index of match?

I can check all groups for *null* or compare *global Value* field with *group Value* fields or separate pattern to many and check them through line of "*if*", but its kinda crappy and gives additional complexity. Is regex don't have some finite state value?

Comment: As you can imagine multiple groups may have a successful match, therefore there is no meaningful way to identify one. Its up to the creator of the expression to check the groups he is interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do this:

```
match.Groups[1].Success // true or false
match.Groups[2].Success // true or false
match.Groups[3].Success // true or false
```

You could also name your groups to make it easier to follow:

```
(?<foo>a)|(?<bar>b)|(?<baz>c)
```

```
match.Groups["foo"].Success // true or false
match.Groups["bar"].Success // true or false
match.Groups["baz"].Success // true or false
```

Comment: Thx for fast answer! It help's me a lot! But, isn't second approach will be slower because of dictionary usage?

Comment: How many million times per second do you want to run this regex?

Comment: @eocron it'll be a really tiny bit slower, but as Blorgbeard said, I doubt it'll be a bottleneck.

Comment: Im trying to create some kind of search engine and have very big regex pattern and stream of files. For each file i have to find matches by this pattern (not creating new instance of string, just find slice bounds). I need maximum perfomance on this tokenization step.

Comment: @eocron if you're building a search engine you should build an inverted index rather than bruteforcing this with regexes. Take a look at Lucene.NET or Lucene on IKVM or something like ElasticSearch.

Comment: No, it's not engine in a way you are talking, it's morphology search engine. I need to analyze full meaning of text being analyzed, not only indexing them.